# How to solve term environment variable not set in ssh

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

when using this script in php:

```
echo "<br>";
echo "<pre>";
echo $ssh->exec('top');
echo "</pre>";
```

I get this error:

TERM Enivronment variable not set.

Answer (score 1):

Do `$ssh->enablePTY()`. See this:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/pty.html#top

Note that you'll have to make use of File_ANSI(), lest the output won't make a lot of sense. eg.

```
$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec('top');
$ssh->setTimeout(5);
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo $ansi->getScreen();
```